# How to frame a like query to perform and operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an stored procedure which returns  result based on what text i send as search string

I have 4 records  with text

```
1  egg whole raw    
2  egg cooked     
3  egg fried omelet    
4  raw  egg and tomatoes
```

I want to perform a like  search such that  if i  specify ' egg ra ' as my search string in my search text box it should  filter and return two rows as result

```
1  egg whole raw
2 raw egg and tomatoes
```

how should my like query be which will return me this result ?

Comment: This shows no research, this answer should be easily find-able using LIKE clause documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where text_column like '%egg%' 
and text_column like '%ra%'
```

But this won't make use of indexes and can be slow.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply .i want to  get the  same result using only one like  statement can it be done? how ?

Comment: if i have to make a dynamic like  query based  on what words i search  what would be its syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It would be best to google about what you want and if you can't make it work then ask another question here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> select * from your_table WHERE **FREETEXT** (text_column, "egg ra");

You have to enable full free text searching in MSSQL to do the above, below are the other options used fro searching for a text.

- CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)
- CONTAINSTABLE (Transact-SQL)
- FREETEXT (Transact-SQL)
- FREETEXTTABLE (Transact-SQL)

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more info -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547%28v=sql.105%29.aspx